# What is the reconnection policy of "persist" switch on "pon" command from pptp-linux package?

Tags: command-line, networking, pptp

I use to establish a connection to my VPN PPTP server by typing:

```
pon MyVPN persist
```

I want to know the reconnection timing details, but I have not found documentation enough about it. Specifically:
    - If there is a disconnection, does the PPTP client attempts to reconnect immediately?
    - What is the frequency of reconnection attemps (5 mins, 15 mins, variable... etc)?
    - The client stop trying to reconnect after some too long period (give-up time) without succeeding (6 hours, 1 day, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As far as i can see the reconnection is immediate (although it sometimes takes some time for it to detect that connection is broken).
2. I believe there's no lag between retries but you can set up it by using *holdoff n* where n is the number of seconds between the disconnection and next try to reconnect.
3. As for a number of retries, it defaults to 10, but you can change it: with *maxfail* option
   you can get all the options by looking at *man pppd*.

Comment: You are right: I was looking for the parameters at *man pon*, instead. As long as *maxfail* defaults to 10, if my VPN PPTP server was off for 1 hour, the PPP connection gave up. I have set it to maxfail=0, that means *Never give up trying to connect*. I have reviewed the full *man pppd*, and these two options seem to be the only related to reconnecting with *pon*. Thanks.